# Error on Swiper type when running npm run build

Tags: reactjs, typescript, next.js, swiper.js

Running **npm run build** on my project gives me the error below. When running npm run dev, it doesn't happens.

```
Type '{ children: Element[]; breakpoints: { 320: { slidesPerView: string; }; 768: { slidesPerView: number; slidesPerColumn: number; slidesPerGroup: number; slidesPerColumnFill: string; spaceBetween: number; allowTouchMove: boolean; }; }; getSwiper: Dispatch<...>; rebuildOnUpdate: boolean; }' is not assignable to type 'ReactIdSwiperProps'.
  Types of property 'breakpoints' are incompatible.
    Type '{ 320: { slidesPerView: string; }; 768: { slidesPerView: number; slidesPerColumn: number; slidesPerGroup: number; slidesPerColumnFill: string; spaceBetween: number; allowTouchMove: boolean; }; }' is not assignable to type '{ [ratio: string]: SwiperOptions; [width: number]: SwiperOptions; }'.
      Property '320' is incompatible with index signature.
        Type '{ slidesPerView: string; }' is not assignable to type 'SwiperOptions'.
          Types of property 'slidesPerView' are incompatible.
            Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'number | "auto"'
```

[image]

The stack of the project:

- React, version 16.13.1
- NextJS, version 10.0.0
- TypeScript, version 3.9.7

[image]

What could be the issue? I'm still learning my way with this stack.

Since it is pointing to the Swiper, the problem may also be linked to it. Then follow the file with the configuration.

```
/**
 * External dependencies.
 */
import React, { FC, useState } from 'react';
import Swiper from 'react-id-swiper';
// Import Swiper styles
import 'swiper/swiper.scss';

/**
 * Internal dependencies.
 */
import { ContentCard } from '../content-card';
import './contents-list-swiper.scss'

/**
 * Typing variables
 */
interface Content {
    title: string;
    excerpt: string;
    badge: string;
    slug: string;
}

interface Props {
    content: Content[];
}

export const ContentsListSwiper: FC<Props> = ({ content }) => {
    const [swiper, updateSwiper] = useState(null);

    const swiperConfig = {
        breakpoints: {
            320: {
                slidesPerView: 'auto',
            },
            768: {
                slidesPerView: 3, // or 'auto'
                slidesPerColumn: 2,
                slidesPerGroup: 3,
                slidesPerColumnFill: 'row',
                spaceBetween: 5,
                allowTouchMove: false,
            },
        },
        getSwiper: updateSwiper,
        rebuildOnUpdate: true,
    }

    return (
        <div className="_contents-list-swiper py-4">
            <div className="">
                <Swiper {...swiperConfig}>
                    {content.map(({ title, excerpt, badge, slug }, index) => (
                        <div className="swiper-slide" key={index}>
                            <ContentCard
                                title={title}
                                excerpt={excerpt}
                                badge={badge}
                                slug={slug}
                            />
                        </div>
                    ))}
                </Swiper>
            </div>
        </div>
    );
}
```